# Loading sql dump into oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, large-files

I had sqlite database which contained nearly 100k entries. SQL features of sqlite turned out to be insufficient for my needs, so i decided to move the whole db to oracle. The only problem is - i have sql dump file, 150mb, and i cant load it into oracle - i just dont know how.
I tried to use oracle's web-based control panel, but it cant upload file as it's too big.

Seems like tools like SQL*Loader work only with data files, but i already have complete sql dump and i wonder how to feed it to Oracle XE.

What shud i do?

Comment: What format is the dump file in? Is it a CSV, SQL queries...?

Comment: as i wrote - sql dump, list of sql queries, including CREATE TABLE, INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dump file is indeed a list of SQL squeries, just run it at a SQL*Plus prompt.

```
prompt> cd my\dump\script\dir
prompt> sqlplus /

Connected to:
Personal Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

sql> @dumpscript.sql
```

Alternatively, open the script in SQL Developer (or equivalent, i.e. TOAD, SquirrelSQL) and run it from there.

Comment: i get these errors: SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

Comment: Seems to be related to the encoding of the file, this may help: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/975448-sp2-0027-input-too-long-2499-characters-line-ignored.html#post3594190

Comment: i dont see how its related to my problem - i DO have lines longer than 2500 characters, because i have large text fields in db. and my file is plain text, so encoding or line breaks cant be the problem. i cant even split values in these text fields :(

Comment: An alternative might be to open the script in SQL Developer, and run it from there (by pressing F5). This should get around the issue as it seems to be SQL*Plus specific.